# AlwaysOn secondary replica unable to switch as primary replica SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, failover, sql-server-2019, alwayson

Problem: we have a 2 node SQL Server AlwaysOn Basic AG setup, where we're unable to failover the AG groups to the current secondary replica and make it the primary replica.

Right now all the databases are in sync across 2 nodes with zero latency. If tried to failover to the current secondary, it comes online on the current-secondary and then the AG gets stuck on failed state.

- Tried to bring manually online - doesn't work
- Restarted ClusterServices - doesn't work
- Restarted secondary replica - doesn't work

Simple terms - the current secondary replica is unable to host/become the primary replica.

Comment: Make sure you have configured listener setting properly.

Comment: Yes, @NP007, everything is setup correctly infact they're even in sync. It's just that i'm unable to switch my secondary as primary. The Failover logs just show they got failed over and unable to bring it online. There's no single clue that is leading me to the solution.

Comment: off-topic - belongs on dba